# Creating a BATCH with multiple INPUTS (variables) to run a workbench that intersects LINES AND POLYGONS

Tags: fme-form, intersection, batch, transformer

I'm trying to create a batch file to run my workbench.fmw in which I have two input files: 8 pipeline shapefiles and 96 communal areas shapefiles. The workbench allows cutting pipeline relative to the areas by using "Spatial Relator" Transformer.

I need to do batch processing in order to run this workbench several times with different inputs automatically (by double clicking on the .bat).

I tried to create my DOS script in a very complicated way so I come to you for help and suggestions and if anyone has ever created a similar batch?

Comment: Just think you need to run the workspace with the workspace_runner see the example http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Creating-a-Web-Map-Tile-Cache-in-SQL-Server

Comment: It is a good suggestion but, do you please have an example of how to use Workspace Runner, because I have never had the opportunity to try it.

Comment: Download the 'how to' from the link provided it contains the fme workspace.